Does the equivalent of an axe kick exist in any Chinese martial arts?
The axe kick is quite common in Japanese and Korean martial arts but despite seeing what appears to be similar in many demonstrations, I haven't been able to find a reliable source stating it as a technique used in any Chinese martial arts. This video demonstration shows a front kick, however it's motion appears to resemble an axe kick much closer than a Japanese or Korean front kick.
I wonder then whether it does exist, but is just named differently, or if it doesn't exist at all, what is the reason?

Axe, hammer, stretch, downward, there are many different names for that type of kick.

It's a good question. Where does the axe kick come from originally? Or specifically, where does Taekwondo get it from? Because I don't see it used in karate. It's not in Savate, which supposedly had an influence on some forms of karate and TKD. It's not in kung-fu that I know about. Maybe I just don't remember or haven't seen a kung fu style with it. That video is not showing an axe kick. Those are leg raises. They're basic conditioning exercises in northern kung-fu. It's not used for martial purposes directly. And they don't utilize the downward stroke.

I believe in Karate the axe kick is known as otoshi-kakato-geri

@FrontEnd Yes, but it could have originally come from Korean versions of karate. That's my guess. You don't see an axe kick by any of the original Okinawan karate in the early 1900's. Classical Okinawan karate does not kick high like that. It could have also come about from sparring entirely on its own. And I say that because the sparring of today bears little resemblance to that of early 1900's Okinawan karate from what I've seen. With more and more people doing it, it evolves. New techniques can come out of that. But where was it used first is the real question. No idea.

It is apparently named pigua tui or xiapi tui and is noted here to be taught in Sanda.
Shifu Yan Lei, from Shaolin tradition, demonstrates it in this video

Nice find, thank you

While the Axe Kick is not as iconic as other Chinese martial arts techniques such as side kick and round kick, it is used, especially in modern forms of CMA.
When you discuss CMA, you need to consider there are arguably hundreds of styles of CMA. These days, while remaining faithful to traditions, to various degrees, many (most/all?) schools take aspects from other martials from around the globe to create a style that fits in with aims and goals of the school.
Blue Belt grading where I train uses an Axe kick pattern, with an Axe kick board break a requirement to pass the grade.

I won't doubt that it may exist somewhere, but it may be worth actually mentioning an example.

I'm not familiar enough with the breadth of Chinese martial arts to say whether some sort of axe kick exists in those traditions.
I can say with confidence that the wushu kick in the video you link to is, like many in CMA generally and especially in wushu, a stretching/conditioning/supplemental exercise and not a technique intended for fighting. The palm-slapping "crescent kick" is another example.
